# distinction between user annotation an other annotations

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

please i have recently made a Map which suppose to show the user location (green pin color) and others annotations for service stations (red pins color), for the moment, i am able to show all annotations with the same color and i still unable to tell the `MKMapView` delegate how to make difference between two pin types and so assign to each type the right title to show.
this is my `MKAnnotationView` method :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";   
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyLocation class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        [annotationView setAnimatesDrop:YES];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

               return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;    
}
```

and for my class which implement the `MKAnnotation` delegate i have this method :

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)enseigneDeLaStation distanceVersLaStation:(NSString *) distanceVersLaStation coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _enseigneDeLaStation = [enseigneDeLaStation copy];
        _distanceVersLaStation = [distanceVersLaStation copy];
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

thx in advance for your help :)

**EDIT**
i try to make the user location annotation like this, please if i am wrong correct me :

```
location2D = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ .latitude = latitudeOfUserLocation, .longitude = longitudeOfUserLocation };
    MyLocation *annotation=[[[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:@"You are here" distanceVersLaStation:@"" coordinate:location2D]autorelease];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

**EDIT 2**
Hi again, i try to make one annotation to make sure it even call the annotation method so imake this simple example :

```
latitudeOfUserLocation=43.2923;
    longitudeOfUserLocation=5.45427;
    location2D = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ .latitude = latitudeOfUserLocation, .longitude = longitudeOfUserLocation };
    MyLocation *annotation=[[[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:@"You are here" distanceVersLaStation:@"coucou" coordinate:location2D]autorelease];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    MKCoordinateSpan span={latitudeDelta:1,longitudeDelta:0.5};
    MKCoordinateRegion region={location2D,span};
    [mapView setRegion:region];
```

when i run the app, i see the region zoomed well which go with the 43.2923/5.45427  but i don't see the annotation, why it's not calling the annotation method,i can't move on since it's not showing the user annotation, please help, thx in advance :)

**EDIT 3**
Hi, i assumed that this has always relation with making difference between user and station pins, so i have declared a var `codeColor`, set it to 1 (the type of the user) when invoking the annotations and set it to 2(station type) when calling the annotations for the stations :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
       codeColor=1;//it's the first type, the user one
    MyLocation *annotation=[[[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:@"You are right here"   distanceVersLaStation:@"" coordinate:location2D]autorelease];
    annotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;  
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

}
```

and :

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{  codeColor=2;
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    MyLocation *annotation=[[[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:ensStation distanceVersLaStation:distance coordinate:location2D]autorelease];
           annotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;  
           [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


           }
```

and for the annotations method :

```
if (codeColor==2) {

            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        }
```

now when testing for the first time, all is ok, the user annotation without button and the station one is with the button, but when i move from the view and i came back, all annotations are with buttons, even the user one. could you please help me there, thx in advance :)

Comment: How are you adding the user location annotation?  Do you want to show a green pin for it or the standard animated blue dot?

Comment: Hi, actually i want to show a green color which is provided by the API

Comment: i have edited my question, i want to notice that both the user and stations annotations call the MyLocation` class which is supposed to make also the difference between the two types to show the appropriate title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to add a pinColor property to your MyLocation class:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) MKPinAnnotationColor pinColor;
```

When creating the annotation, set the pinColor:

```
MyLocation *annotation=[[[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:@"You are here" distanceVersLaStation:@"" coordinate:location2D]autorelease];
annotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;  //or red or whatever
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

and in the viewForAnnotation method:

```
//...
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
annotationView.pinColor = ((MyLocation *)annotation).pinColor;
```

Comment: Hi Anna, your idea seems good, but nothing is changed, all annotations have the same color, also the title is not changed for the user annotation ("You are here").. any way, i still working on that and i'm following your idea

Comment: Hi Anna, i have noticed that the annotation of the user didn't even showed although i make the same code for both the user and the stations annotations, please take a look for my 2nd EDIT, thx :)

Comment: Code looks fine.  Are you sure addAnnotation line is getting executed (put a breakpoint there)?  What changes did you make since it was working?

Comment: Hi, i puted a breakpoint at that line : `[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];` and i got that in the console : `Pending breakpoint 1 - ""StationsSurLaCarteViewController.m":102" resolved` does that mean it's ok ??

Comment: Is that line highlighted in purple in the code editor?  Then yes.  Click Continue or from the menu Run|Continue to finish running the app.

Comment: well, yes, it's in purple color, i continue the app run, and the annotation isn't there, by the way, i haven't changed any code posted in my question :(

Comment: Zoom out to the whole world, do you see the annotation?  Try commenting out the whole viewForAnnotation method and run it (you can disable the breakpoint).  Do you see a red pin?

Comment: well, i have figured it out, this line ` [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
` was puted after the current location annotation, so it remove it and i see nothing, now i have move it to the beginning of my code and all is ok, i will take back now my annotation distinction problem and i will keep you updated concerning the distinction between user and station annotation, thx for your patience with me Anna :)

Comment: Hi again, i'am currently on displaying the `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` which appear on the right of the pin when it's called out, so i have to make difference, between the two types of pin, the one of the user shouldn't have this button, please have a look on my EDIT, i tried to make a float variable `codeColor`, if it's equal 2, i make button to the pin, else i don't, however, that's make all the pins with button.

Comment: First, codeColor should be int instead of float for reliable comparisons.  Second, it should be a property of your MKAnnotation object like pinColor.  Third, set the callout view to nil if codeColor is not 2.